# HTTP Error 404.7 - Not Found Due to Response.Redirect Method in AspDOTnet CSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtUsername.Text != string.Empty && txtPassword.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                DBWPAccountRecordsDataContext DBACCOUNT = new DBWPAccountRecordsDataContext();
                var query = (from i in DBACCOUNT.WP_LoginUsers
                             where i.Login_Username == txtUsername.Text && i.Login_Password == txtPassword.Text
                             select new { 
                                 ACCESS = i.Login_AccessPortID,
                                 LOGID = i.Login_UserID
                             });
                if (query.Count() > 0)
                {
                    getLoginUserPROFILEID(query.FirstOrDefault().LOGID);
                    getUserLoginDepartment(query.FirstOrDefault().ACCESS, WPGlobalVariables.getPROFUSERID);
                    Session["ACCESS"] = query.FirstOrDefault().ACCESS;
                    Response.Redirect("~/Modules/MasterPage.Master");
                }
                else 
                {
                    lblResult.Visible = true;
                    lblResult.Text = "Account Doesn't Exist!";
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                lblResult.Visible = true;
                lblResult.Text = "Username / Password is Empty";                
            }
        }
```

Hello sir & maam.. i'm a student of Computer Science Junior Level Focusing on the DotNet Framework this button happens to be on a MasterPage1.page which i created and set as a start-up or landing page of a site. and its a master login page which users try to add login filters out adminiters and users. not when someone login it suppost to redirect the page to another master page which is stored in inside a folder "Modules" which consist pages of site map based on Session ID of a login user. although when the login is successful it doesn't show up. but an error is shown stating "HTTP Error 404.7 - Not Found The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension." is it possible to have two master pages in one Project?

Comment: Response.Redirect("~/Modules/Users/Home.aspx")

I've set the Redirect Node to a web form i created that inherits the 2nd master page which is working fine for right now but the problem is i'm not sure for any future conflict that maybe encountered using this style. please do correct me if i'm doing it wrong.. i'm new in asp.net c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in  `Response.Redirect("~/Modules/MasterPage.Master");` Try redirecting to desired aspx page having the above master page. As master pages are not served by the IIS.

Say you have a logged in page named LoggedIn.Aspx, that is displayed after a successful login inside the module directory,  then use the code below

```
Response.Redirect("~/Modules/LoggedIn.aspx");
```

Comment: thank you sir for the knowledge. it's a big help i tried it works ok.

Comment: I will be more glad, if you mark it as answer. If it really helped you. :)